# Is "What did mummy told you? " - Is this correct?

Tags: grammar

> What did mummy told you?

Is this a correct sentence?

Or it should be:

> What did mummy **tell** you?

Can you give an explanation why one or the other?

Comment: Because of your auxiliary verb "did" you should use the base form of the verb "tell". It is the same with other auxiliary verbs, i.e., we use the base form of the verbs when we have an auciliary whether in question or sentence.

Comment: Technically, "mummy" isn't used in proper context, so no. @Sina is correct; "tell" would be the correct word in that sentence.

Comment: It's "correct" if the speaker is about 2 years old! It's not correct if the speaker is anyone else, for example, a parent or grandparent.

Comment: Who said it?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choices are

> What *had* Mummy *told* you?
>   What *did* Mummy *tell* you?
>   What *has* Mummy *told* you?

you can figure this out by answering the questions

> Mummy *had told* me that you were going to buy me a sweetie.
>   Mummy *did tell* me that you were going to buy me a sweetie.
>   Mummy *has told* me that you were going to buy me a sweetie.

If you used

> Mummy *did told* me...
>   Mummy *had tell* me...
>   Mummy *has tell* me...

it would be incorrect.

In the case of a two year old, they would probably only say

> Mummy told me you were going to buy me a sweetie. *( Where is it?! )*

Comment: Why not "What *has* Mummy told you?"

Comment: @ColleenV Fair point, I was just echoing the choices given by the OP.

Comment: I read the sentence as a parental rhetorical question complete with a lot of eyebrow wiggling - "And what has Mummy told you about taking candy from strangers?" It may be an AmE difference, but I can't think of a situation where I would say "What had Mummy told you?" as a question. I might say "What was it that Mummy had told you?".